# Funding custom weapon development in a friendly foreign country?

Tags: internal-consistency, military-defense

If you have a country with unique needs for some kind of weapon system but it doesn't have a domestic industry to produce it, is it possible to fund the development in a friendly foreign country?

Comment: what do you mean with "unique needs"?

Comment: Why would it not be “possible” to buy something from a country you’ve not told us anything about?  No it's not possible because they’re religions fanatics, or don’t allow that kind of export, or you can’t affort it…

Comment: Of course, this kind of thing happens a lot within the EU for example. It would however be very unusual if the country funds it to 100% since most of the time the "friendly foreign country" would benefit a lot and would be willing to pay for it in order to have it developed in their country. Do you want 100% funding by your nation?

Comment: @L.Dutch Something peculiar to the needs for the country that nothing off the shelf fits.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Yes and I don't want the foreign country to sell it to my neighbors without my approval.  In other words I control the IP for that system.

Comment: @Saren This just sounds to me like a matter of negotiating a good agreement and not a question of whether this is could potentially happen. It is however highly unusual. What kind of weapon? Why develop a weapon instead of just buying it? What kind of country has enough money to fund the development and such a special request but no industry? Usually weapons get developed to make money not to waste it. This is the weak point of your premise if you ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Germany managed to fund, research and develop their early [tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grosstraktor) in Russian [tank schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_tank_school) and factories (of all places) after being not allowed to work on them in Germany following the Treaty of Versailles.

So I think it's proven that you *can* "fund custom weapon development in a friendly foreign country". I'd even say "friendly" is optional.

Comment: This was only realistic though because Germany certainly had the industry to produce those tanks eventually. I mean that part is actual history

Answer (score 3):

The point of the domestic military industrial complex is to create jobs and maintain your own nation's technological lead. If your nation doesn't have the technology, you try to acquire it. If your nation doesn't have the industrial base, you build it.

Maintaining the military industrial system may appear to be money down the drain, but it's money down the drain within your domestic economy, it stays within the domestic economy for some time and, directly and indirectly, employs a lot of people. It's tax money that goes straight back to the population. You buy the raw materials from your own mines, even if someone else is cheaper. You contract your own factories, your own shipyards. Keep the money in the country and keep it moving around entirely within the domestic economy as much as possible.

One may buy in complete weapons systems, often aircraft, but one very rarely funds someone else to develop it, as that's paying for someone else to have a technological lead over you.

Comment: However, it's mostly the norm nowadays. Up to the modern era, yes, every country produced its own swords, arrows or plate armors. With the invention of the cannon, though, it was usually better to buy high quality cannons from somewhere else than to develop a technology you lacked of. It's much more certain today: you buy F-18 or Leopard tanks, you don't create your own weapon systems unless you have both a lot of money and long-term plans to become a superpower (China) or fears of being isolated and not allowed to purchase weaponry from elsewhere (Israel).

Comment: I don't have aircraft industry but I'm earning a lot of coins from exporting heavy equipment machinery.  If I need some aircraft unique to my military needs do I have to start an aircraft company for one single project.

Comment: @Saren, if you have no industry then you can either buy in and modify, building up your industry by doing so, or buy custom and hope that your "friendly" partner doesn't rip off your technology.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like France building a ship for Russia? Or Israel for... well anyone who want to buy UZI? Or Poland organizing an auction for possible choppers?

**Yes** Everything is possible if you have money.

You can order totally custom piece of equipment (with brand new R&D), you can order custom build of existing one or you can just get one off the shelf.

But remember to not attack manufacturer country with the weapon they made for you. They are the first one to have a counter measure for that.

Comment: The examples you gave don't fit my needs since Mistral  and UZI were created for French / Israeli military. France & Israel are selling them  with probably some customization like Russian weapon system on the ship. I want something that France / Israel do not have and have little use for. Like instead of 65 tons Merkava I want Israel to make me a light tank.

Comment: This is the second case. Custom build. The first is case is usually secret between countries due to, well, spies and all that jazz.